# Burning calories: Using elliptical type equipment

Tags: exercise, exercise-equipment

While ellipticals offer stationary movement with low impact on the knees, they also seem to offer burning off insane amounts of calories when compared to equal time/work on a treadmill.

```
Same brand equipment, similar workout profiles

~200 calories 30 minutes on a treadmill 
~670 calories 30 minutes on an eliptical
~200 calories 30 minutes on a bike
```

I've heard from many different sources including personal trainers both sides that ellipticals are great for burning calories and also that they are just lies.

The equipment I have at home all have a calorie counter that continues to climb even if i'm stationary. It's making assumptions about my effort to determine calories burned so I dont believe either one.

The equipment at gyms ask for weight, height and even use your heart rate to determine your calories burned.

The spread between the treadmill and the elliptical calories burned readings both from my home equipment and the gym equipment are very similar.

What is the truth? Does the eliptical really just burn 2-3 times more calories per session than a treadmill?

Comment: related: [Calorie counter on an exercise machine is it actual or approximation](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/calorie-counter-on-an-exercise-machine-is-it-actual-or-approximation?rq=1)

Comment: related: [Calorie Counter from heart rate monitor Vs. Elliptical machine](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3201/calorie-counter-from-heart-rate-monitor-vs-elliptical-machine?rq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find it highly unlikely that you would burn more calories on an eliptical trainer than running at a similar pace on the treadmill. The treadmill is more like using free weights, whereas the elliptical trainer just needs a push in somewhat the right direction to keep going round. Also, pushing with one leg automatically moves the other, which is almost like a free lunch!

Basically: all the things that make it great are also what make it bad.

- Yes, it has lower impacts on the knees, but that also means your knee extending muscles are trained less.
- Yes, using your arms increases the intensity of the workout, but because the arms drive the legs, that's all energy your legs aren't going to provide. You win some, you loose some.
- Also the enforced stride length may not be the right one for you, depending on your size and physical condition. Running at a different frequency effects the efficiency and intensity of the workout as well.
- And lastly, the resistance on an elliptical trainer comes from a fly wheel, that requires air resistance. [As I explained on another question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/312/home-gym-is-an-elliptical-trainer-alone-enough) this doesn't scale very naturally. So to workout at 75-80% of your maximal heart rate, which is probably what you would need for ~700 calories/30 minutes, you'd have either a ridiculous frequency or abnormal high resistance.

As for finding out the truth: I highly recommend you try all the devices with the same heart rate monitor, rather than trusting the built in one. That way you can compare the increases in heart rate when you increase the resistance of the machine in three/four steps. Do that for the elliptical trainer, bike and treadmill and you get a much better idea of whether it actually measures correctly.

Final note: it's more important you do something that's fun, so if the elliptical trainer makes you come back more often, than go for it! Also, [there's a study that showed that elliptical trainers can be a great replacement during the winter times](http://digitalcommons.wku.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1241&context=ijes&sei-redir=1#search="Elliptical+trainer+heart+rate+vo2max"), but they had to workout at 80% of their maximal heart rate, which was comparable to the intensity of their normal running exercise and the runners complained it was hard to keep this up. **Either way: 3x more calories than on a treadmill is absolutely not possible!**

Comment: Also note that it is not so simple to find out your maximum heart rate. Things like 220-age are not reliable! Some people say a max intensity 10km run with sprint finish will give you an idea... All the calories calculation in gym equipment is, I believe, bogus. They may have measured some skinny, mid weight and heavier people in different age groups and interpolate between the datasets. Most likely they have not done this with 1000 of people so it won't be representative.

Comment: @Ivo great answer. It covers all of what i've found in my own research. However, the elipticals don't all use air resistence (actually think thats just the first models only). All of the machines i've used and own use either a magnetic system or a belt tensioner.

Comment: Well in either case @Dustin, they won't adjust the resistance based on your range of motion, so it will become harder and harder to get it rotate over the extremes. Off course the arms can help in this regard, but it's not 'normal' running

Comment: @Ivo i agree with your point.

Comment: @Martin While I agree that it's hard to get a direct measurement (you can buy a device that measures lactic acid to find out anaerobic threshold) if you use your own heart rate monitor regularly it's pretty easy to get a feel for it. If your running, you hit your anaerobic threshold at the pace where you don't feel like you can keep going for an hour. 10% more than than it your max is the beginning of your V02 Max.

Comment: @Martin (cont) The problem with assigning a finite number is, it changes. If you do workouts that push hard into your anaerobic range, your body will adapt and your threshold will increase. Ie, the harder you work out the harder you will be able to work out in the future. Back when I was 20 when I was doing hard sprints a few times a week and was in much better shape I could actually get my heart rate up into the 190s and could sustain 1/2 to 1 mile sprints with my rate in the mid 180's.

Comment: @Evan, perhaps we should have a question about how to determine your VO2max without getting tested in a lab!

Comment: @Martin (cont) As far as the calorie counters go, I agree. Even if their figures were right they only consider the calories you burn while you work out. If you're in the low heart rate ranges they'd be more accurate but at those ranges your heart and metabolism slow back down after a workout. In the aerobic and anaerobic ranges your body will go on to continue burning calories throughout the day.

Comment: @Ivo sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: And feel free to come to our chat room if you like some discussing! @Evan

Comment: @Ivo, something that occurred to me on this question.  Regarding the "3x calories!" marketing-speak.  Quite simply, the machine could be set on a difficult resistance or slope.  There's no particular natural correspondence between jogging and "using an elliptical". So, the guy writing the ad brochure simply set the elliptical on, whatever resistance, produced "three times!" the calorie burn. After all - very simply, I could claim "running uses 3x the calories of an elliptical!!!"  I'm sure that if you run at a certain **very high speed, perhaps up a hill** that is quite true.